# Error when installing KDE

Tags: linux, kde, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install KDE as my desktop environment on my ubuntu 16.04, but I'm getting this error

> E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

How Can I resolve it?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser... Did you consider to install directly Kubuntu? BTW the last long term version of Ubuntu (/Kubuntu) is the 18.04 LTS.

Comment: If I understand exactly what you mean, I used "sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop" to run the installation.

Comment: KDE relies on Qt, which isn't trivial to integrate with Ubuntu.  You're asking for trouble starting with Ubuntu and adding the desktop.  Kubuntu has a dedicated team integrating KDE with Ubuntu.  Start by just installing Kubuntu.  There are a number of packages you need besides just kubuntu-desktop.  I ran into problems myself trying to create Mint KDE by installing the kubuntu desktop.  It might be helpful to look at https://superuser.com/questions/1366883/identify-source-of-phantom-screen-locker-in-mint-kde-via-kubuntu.